# When to use Optional<T> vs OptionalT in JDK 8+ (where T is boxed primitive type)?

Tags: java, scala, java-8, option-type, api-design

It seems for [performance reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323019/why-have-multiple-version-of-optional-in-java-8) [`OptionalDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalDouble.html) does not simply extend [`Optional<Double>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)? IMO, that's a perf concern that should not have leaked into SDK design but I digress.

As a library writer, which one should I expose to my users, `Optional<T>` or `OptionalT`? What factors would make me decide which one to use when?

EDIT:
Based on the comments, elaborating my particular use case. I am writing a bridge to a Scala ML library so people can use it from Java 8+.

The boiled down Scala signature looks like this:

```
def flattenBy(f: Double => Option[Double]): List[Double]
```

For those not familiar with Scala, `flattenBy` is a function that takes in another function from `Double` to `Option[Double]` and returns a `List` of `Doubles`.

What is the closest signature this maps to in Java 8?

Comment: Well `Optional<Double>` isn't an `Optional<Primitive>`, because the genuine primitive would be `double` - which isn't a valid type argument.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sorry `Primitive` is a misnomer here (updated in edit) but the question still stands - which one is the preferred type to expose in APIs?

Comment: I think your question stems from a misunderstanding around the primitive wrapper classes (which isn't always helped by the JMV's "helpful" autoboxing). Primitives are just that - primitive. They're not instances of a class. They can be *boxed* to a corresponding class, but that does incur a performance hit, which is mentioned in your link. So to repeat what @JonSkeet said, `OptionalDouble` is not a subtype of `Optional<Double>`.

Comment: @TomG: I see. As a library writer, which one should I expose in my interface? If the answer is "it depends" - what does it depend on? When do I use one vs the other?

Comment: What is your use case? These classes are easy to misuse.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: I intentionally kept the question open-ended and not tied to a particular use case so readers can get general guidelines about what to apply where. I can elaborate on my particular use case if need be.

Comment: I doubt that there are noticeable performance differences. There is a semantic difference. An `Optional<Double>` doesn’t know whether it has to retain the object identity of the wrapped `Double` object (and will retain it), while for an `OptionalDouble`, it’s clear that the object identity is irrelevant (as there is none).

Comment: @Holger: Then I guess the question begs why didn't the Java library designers make `OptionalDouble` extend `Optional<Double>`? I got the performance as a reason from an accepted answer on SO that I linked in the OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323019/why-have-multiple-version-of-optional-in-java-8

Comment: See the top answer here for general advice on when to use `Optional` and when not to use `Optional`:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type. You should only return `Optional<Double>` if the identity is needed. In 99% of cases, you should use `OptionalDouble`.

Comment: There might be performance considerations—the same as for adding all the mirrored functional interfaces for `int`, `long` and `double`. But being based on performance considerations is not contradicting to *my* doubts about the practical consequences. And *you* might base your decision on either or both…

Comment: @PaulBoddington: My question is if I do decide to use Optionals, do I use `Optional<T>` or `OptionalT`. Also, in this particular case, its not only something I am returning, its also an argument into an API I am exposing.

I guess to further elaborate on my use case: I am providing a Java 8 bridge to my clients to a Scala ML library that uses `Option[X]` (in idiomatic Scala, `null`s are avoided and `Option[A]` is used instead). In my Java interface, which one do I expose? Also, I have complicated Scala signatures like `f: Double => Option[Double]`. What should that map to in JDK8+?

Comment: I don't know Scala at all I'm afraid. I don't really understand your question as there is no such thing as `OptionalT`. If your method is generic with type parameter `T`, your only choice is to return `Optional<T>`. On the other hand if your method is not generic, then you should prefer `OptionalDouble` to `Optional<Double>`. You should not use an `Optional` as a method argument at all. As that link explains, they are only intended as return values.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: tl;dr: I have some function in Scala that accepts another function as an argument from `Double` to `Option[Double]`. In Scala, the signature for the latter function is `Double => Option[Double]`. What is the closest thing I should map to in Java 8?

Comment: You could pass a `DoubleFunction<OptionalDouble>`

Comment: @PaulBoddington: I put my use case in the EDIT. And, yes, I could. But, what makes me decide `DoubleFunction<OptionalDouble>` over `DoubleFunction<Optional<Double>>`?

Comment: You should only use an `Optional<Double>` if you actually need the the doubles to have an identity as well as a value (it sounds like you don't). It looks to me like it should be `List<Double> flattenBy(DoubleFunction<OptionalDouble> f) {...}`

Comment: @PaulBoddington: Fair enough. Please put it as an answer so I can accept it. Alternatively, this question already has 4 close votes (not sure why?) so I guess its not appropriate for this site so feel free to close it too.

Comment: I have no idea why there are 4 close votes. It's not from me. I usually ask for clarification rather than vote to close.

Comment: Scala's `Optional` is not specialized, so it always contains an object value. So a direct mapping would be to a boxed `Double`. From a Java api design, if the signature is always a `Double` then prefer `OptionalDouble`. This will be more valuable when value types are supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like the closest signature is:

```
List<Double> flattenBy(DoubleFunction<OptionalDouble> f)
```

You would only need to use `Optional<Double>` if it is necessary for the doubles to have an identity as well as a value (It sounds like you don't need this).

Answer (score 1):

> It seems for performance reasons OptionalDouble does not simply extend Optional? IMO, that's a perf concern that should not have leaked into SDK design but I digress.

That's not quite what the linked answer says. It explains that `OptionalDouble` exists *at all* because of the performance concern. But given that it does it can't extend `Optional<Double>` because the signatures are incompatible: its `get` returns `double`, `Optional<Double>`'s one returns `Double`.

If you don't care about types other than `double`, sure, use `OptionalDouble`; but consider that `List<Double>` has a much worse overhead ([3 times the memory use of `double[]` in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585947/listdouble-that-uses-ram-of-double/8589338#8589338))! There are many libraries providing real primitive collections for Java: e.g. [HPPC](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html), [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/), [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/), [Koloboke](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Koloboke).